# React, problem with rendering images with spaces in their name

Tags: javascript, reactjs

I have a problem with my React-Express application, images with spaces in names are not rendered in the application, but the path is correct.
Images with no spaces in names work well.
The paths are correct and work in the browser because % replacing spaces.

[image: Img with space:]
[image: Image without space]
Component for uploading images:

```
const FileUpload = () => {
const [file, setFile] = useState('');
const [filename, setFilename] = useState('Choose File');
const [uploadedFile, setUploadedFile] = useState({});
const [message, setMessage] = useState('');
const [uploadPercentage, setUploadPercentage] = useState(0);

const onChange = e => {
  setFile(e.target.files[0]);
  setFilename(e.target.files[0].name);
};

const onSubmit = async e => {
e.preventDefault();
const formData = new FormData();
formData.append('file', file);

try {
  const res = await axios.post('/uploads', formData, {
    headers: {
      'Content-Type': 'multipart/form-data'
    }
  });

  const { fileName, filePath } = res.data;

  setUploadedFile({ fileName, filePath });

  setMessage('File Uploaded');
} catch (err) {
  if (err.response.status === 500) {
    setMessage('There was a problem with the server');
  } else {
    setMessage(err.response.data.msg);
  }
}
  };
```

Return:

```
  return (
   <Fragment>
    <form onSubmit={onSubmit}>
    <div className='custom-file mb-4'>
      <input
        type='file'
        className='custom-file-input'
        id='customFile'
        onChange={onChange}
      />
      <label className='custom-file-label' htmlFor='customFile'>
        {filename}
      </label>
    </div>
    <input
      type='submit'
      value='Upload'
    />
  </form>
  {uploadedFile ? (
    <div>
      <div>
        <h3>{uploadedFile.fileName}</h3>
        <img src={uploadedFile.filePath} alt={uploadedFile.fileName} /> // Image here
      </div>
    </div>
  ) : null}
   </Fragment>
  );
 };

 export default FileUpload;
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can process those paths with `encodeURI` first, to escape any special characters: https://www.w3schools.com/jsref/jsref_encodeuri.asp

> This function encodes special characters, except: , / ? : @ & = + $ # (Use `encodeURIComponent()` to encode these characters).

`'/uploads/350 x 150.png'` becomes `'/uploads/350%20x%20150.png'`